# Logos missing after Wordpress migration

Tags: wordpress, plugins, migration

For some reason I cant find a place to edit the header logo. The logo will appear in chrome browser. In most browsers, it will just be a blank square and say logo.

This all happened after a migration to a different server/database.

There is some info about plugins needing an authentication key. However, Im unsure if this is the problem as it requires purchase. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to purchase anything. Since you mentioned that this happened after migration. This could be a source issue, the url of the image could be broken or still leading to the old website url. You can check this by going to the DevTools on chrome by tapping F12. Then, click colsole to check if there's an error and let us know about it.

Comment: you were right about the URL. it worked if I used the old url for the site.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear on why this would happen as there are a number of reasons.

Here are a few main things to check:

1. Did the `wp-content/uploads/` folder get copied across fully?
2. If point-1 is correct, can you access the logo file via URL?
3. Are you using a theme builder to add in the logo? If so, you might need to export and import a theme builder file.

Comment: Whatever was sent to me from the old web-designer is uploaded successfully. As for point (3), I cant even add in a header logo. Theres no option anywhere. How would I go about exporting/importing a theme builder?

Comment: @MontgommeryJR You should check if your theme builder has this function first of all. Normally under the builder's settings.

If not, I'd confirm if point-2 works?